# Codeigniter Form with multiple insert row

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add multiple rows with multiple duplicated forms, im stucked at the model.

1# I add player, player can have 1 or N jobs.

2# When creating a player you may add 1 or many jobs in the same form. By default I only show 1 input for 1 job, but if you click in the button a new input shows up to fill up a new job for that new player.

My view:

```
Name<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" />

Jobs<input type="text" name="jobs[0]" value="<?php echo set_value('jobs[0]'); ?>" />

<button id="add_job">Add new job</button>

<!-- if button click, jquery add new input -->
Jobs 2<input type="text" name="jobs[1]" value="<?php echo set_value('jobs[1]'); ?>" />
```

My controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[64]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('jobs[]', 'job', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[64]');

...

$this->players_model->create_player($img['file_name'])
```

My model:

```
function create_player($pic)
{
    $new_member_insert_data = array(  
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'pic' => $pic
    );
    $insert = $this->db->insert('players', $new_member_insert_data);
    $id_player = $this->db->insert_id();

    // problem starts here
    $new_member_insert_jobs = array();

    //for() {
        $new_member_insert_jobs [] = array(
            'id_player' => $id_player,
            'job' => $this->input->post('jobs')[]
        );
    //}
    $this->db->insert_batch( 'estudios', $new_member_insert_jobs );
```

Comment: $new_member_insert_jobs is an array, but no values assigned

Comment: Looks ok, except I'm not sure about the `'job' => $this->input->post('jobs')[]` This value being an array might screw up the `insert_batch`

Answer (score 0):

you can try code

```
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $job= $this->input->post('job');

            $count =count($this->input->post('job')); //number job
            $data2 =array();
                for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)  
                {
                                  $data2[] = array(
                  'name' => $name,
                                     'job' => $job[$i],
                                     );     
                                }
         $this->db->insert_batch('estudios', $data2);
```